# Read map item into a class member

Tags: flutter

I have the following JSON data that I'm loading into my Flutter application:

```
{
    "Games": [
        {
            "name": "Sample Name",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "name": "Category 1",
                    "multiplier": 1,
                    "order": 2
                },
                {
                    "name": "Category 2",
                    "order": 9,
                    "Range": [
                        {
                            "ceiling": 0,
                            "floor": 0,
                            "score": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "ceiling": 1,
                            "floor": 1,
                            "score": 2
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Category 4",
                    "multiplier": -1,
                    "order": 11,
                    "penalty": true
                },
                {
                    "name": "Category 5",
                    "multiplier": 1,
                    "order": 8
                },
                {
                    "name": "Category 6",
                    "multiplier": -1,
                    "order": 10,
                    "penalty": true
                }
            ],
            "enabled": true,
            "maxPlayers": 4,
            "minPlayers": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using the following code to populate the object from map of the above:

```
class Entry {
  String name;
  // final String filename;
  int minPlayers;
  int maxPlayers;
  bool enabled;
  bool selected = false;
  DocumentReference reference;
  List<Category> categories;

  Entry.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference}) {
    name = map['name'];
    enabled = map['enabled'];
    minPlayers = map['minPlayers'];
    maxPlayers = map['maxPlayers'];

    categories =
        (map['categories'].map((data) => Category.fromMap(data)).toList());
  }

class Category {
  String name;
  int order;
  int multiplier;
  bool penalty;

  Category.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {DocumentReference reference}) {
    name = map['name'];
    order = map['order'];
    multiplier = map['multiplier'];
    penalty = !map.containsKey('penalty');
  }

  Category.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);
}
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

How can I get the collection of category elements into an iterable list of objects to hold each category, loading it from an individual element in map['categories']?

Comment: the json you entered is not valid, can you please post a valid one?

Comment: I have updated the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code a little bit, but i removed the reference because i don't have access to its code.
I tried it and it works fine

```
class Entry{
  String name;
  // final String filename;
  int minPlayers;
  int maxPlayers;
  bool enabled;
  bool selected;
  List<Category> categories;
  Entry({
    this.name,
    this.minPlayers,
    this.maxPlayers,
    this.enabled,
    this.categories,
    this.selected =false
  });

  factory Entry.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Entry(
      name: map['name'],
      enabled: map['enabled'],
      minPlayers: map['minPlayers'],
      maxPlayers: map['maxPlayers'],
      categories: Category.fromList(map['categories'])
    );
  }
  static List<Entry> fromList(List json) {
    return json.map((entry) => Entry.fromMap(entry)).toList();
  }
}

class Category {
  String name;
  int order;
  int multiplier;
  bool penalty;
  Category(
    {
      this.name,
      this.order,
      this.multiplier,
      this.penalty
    }
  );

  factory Category.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {

    return Category(
      name :map['name'],
      order : map['order'],
      multiplier : map['multiplier'],
      penalty : map['penalty'] ?? false  
    );
  }

  static List<Category> fromList(List json) {
    return json.map((category) => Category.fromMap(category)).toList();
  }

}
```

and to decode the example you provided use:

```
List<Entry> entries = Entry.fromList(test["Games"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not created valid dart class for your respective json. Your json is having architecture like Entry class is contain multiple game,

Each game has multiple categories,

Each category having multiple Range.

**Please use [this](https://app.quicktype.io/) tools to convert your json into Dart class**

I already create model class for your json please check [this](https://app.quicktype.io?share=UqPURnZeO4jDdbpHMWEs) link.

Now it's time to parsing. I just rename welcome class into Entry.

**Parsing**

```
 final jsonResponse = json.decode('YOUR JSON STRING');
Entry entry =Entry.fromJson(jsonResponse);
print(entry.games.length);
entry.games.map((game) {
  print("Game Name " + game.name + "----------");
  print("Category List");
  game.categories.map((category) {
    print(category.name);

  }).toList();
}).toList();
```

Now Check Debug console. All categories and Game display.